# Space complexity of Bubble sort

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis, space-complexity

I have the following implementation of Bubble sort where it calls a helper method named `swap`.

```java
    public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] array) {
        boolean didSwap = true;
        int j;
        int unsortedUntilIndex = array.length - 1;
    
        // i goes from 0 to array.length - 2
        // j goes from 1 to array.length - 1
        while (didSwap) {
            didSwap = false;
            // for arrays of size 0 or 1 this for loop will never execute
            for (int i = 0; i < unsortedUntilIndex; i++) {
                j = i + 1;
                if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                    swap(i, j, array);
                    didSwap = true;
                }
            }
            unsortedUntilIndex -= 1; // shortens iterations as numbers at highest indices settle into place with each iteration
        }
        return array;
    }
    
    public static void swap(int i, int j, int[] array) {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
```

It seems to me that by simply removing the helper method and including its code inline in the main method, I can reduce the space complexity from *O(N)* to *O(1)* since I'd no longer be adding method calls onto the call stack. Am I interpreting this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `swap` is not recursive so the depth of the call stack is always constant. While it is true that the space complexity of your algorithm is $O(n)$, it is also true that it is $O(1)$ (if we don't count the size needed for the input array `array`).

Inlining the function `swap` makes no difference as far as the asymptotic space complexity is considered.

Comment: it is **not** $O(1)$ if we don't count the input. Since the `for` loop goes through the entire array, the minimum size that `i` needs is at least $\Omega(\log(n))$. Hence, the space complexity is actually $\Omega(\log(n))$

Comment: Depends if you are using the uniform cost model or the logarithmic cost model. In the uniform cost model you assume that numbers fit in a single word of memory and you count the number of used memory words. In the logarithmic cost of model the space is indeed $\Omega(\log n)$ (but, e.g., the time would also be $\Omega(n^2 \log n)$).